# User with reputation of 74 points can review?

Tags: discussion, reputation, review

I have made some edits for posts, mostly updating code spacing for better readability. And I check review status for my suggestions - looking for comments from reviewers if there are any good/bad comments about my suggestion.

For this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253310/sharepoint-content-inventory-using-powershedll-script) I made an [edit](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/95365) which was approved by two people - one of them is [user](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/50444/mohammad-akilan) with 74 reputation points. As I understand, [reviewing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) as a feature is enabled, once reached 2000 points of reputation. How is this possible?

I have nothing against the user, question, edit or approval. I am just curious how the system works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you were editing the specific users post, he have the right to approve your edit even though he doesn't have privileges to do so on other posts. This user doesn't have access to the Suggested Edit review queue https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/

Comment: That explains everything - Thank you.